# Disable treenode in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I would like to make a  tree node disable in primefaces... do you have any idea?
I use this code:

```
<p:tree value="#{treeSelectionView.root1}" var="doc"
                selectionMode="checkbox"
                selection="#{treeSelectionView.selectedNodes2}">
        <p:treeNode icon="ui-icon-note">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
        <p:treeNode type="document" icon="ui-icon-document">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>
        <p:treeNode type="picture" icon="ui-icon-image">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>
        <p:treeNode type="mp3" icon="ui-icon-video">
            <h:outputText value="#{doc.name}" />
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does 'disable the tree' mean that its items cannot be selected anymore?

If yes, you can achieve it by setting all treenodes to not selectable:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TreeSelectionView
{

    private boolean disableTree;
    private TreeNode root1;
    public TreeNode getRoot1()
    {
        setSelectableRecursive(root1,disableTree);
        return root1 ;
    }

    private void setSelectableRecursive(TreeNode node, boolean val)
    {
        node.setSelectable(val);
        for(TreeNode child: node.getChildren())
        {
            setSelectableRecursive(child, val);
        }
    }
}
```